# Accessing lifecycle method's variable from outside of the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My container component has *componentWillMount()* method which returns ***token***. So, i need to access value of this ***token*** from outside of the component. And *console.log(token)* which goes right before exporting ***ContainerComponent*** gives me ***undefined***.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Component1 from '../components/Component1.js';
import * as actions from '../actions/index.js';


class ContainerComponent extends Component{

    componentWillMount(){
        var url = window.location.href;

        var urlLength = url.length;
        var equalSignPos = url.search('=');
        var token = url.substring(equalSignPos+1, urlLength);

        document.cookie = `token=${token}`;
        console.log('token=',token);
        return token;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Component1 DataInputParam={this.props.counterValue} BtnClickHandler={this.props.buttonClickedMethod} />            
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        counterValue: state.RequestButtonCounterReducer,
        tokenValue: state.TokenReducer
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        buttonClickedMethod: () => dispatch(actions.buttonClicked())
    };
};

console.log(token);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContainerComponent);
```

P.S: I want ***token*** to be exported to the redux-store then.

Comment: First of all there's no need to return anything in `componentWillMount` method. It's only lifecycle hook that's called when component will be mounted. To save token in redux store you need to write proper action creator and reducer for that.

Comment: @lukaleli  My situation at the moment: i have an action creator and reducer which works fine. For example, if i'm exporting a **token** from **ContainerComponent** as a `var token = 'xoken' `  (instead of `console.log(token)` ) and importing this token in my reducer, then i'm getting 'xoken' in my store! So, now i just need to put value from `componentWillMount`'s local variable `token` (which gets returned) to `var token` which i'm exporting (instead of `console.log(token)` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an action for receiving a new token and an action creator for that action. If you have actions and action creators for that, then use those.

```
const RECEIVED_NEW_TOKEN = 'RECEIVED_NEW_TOKEN';
```

and

```
const actions = {
    ...
    setToken: (token) => ({ type: RECEIVED_NEW_TOKEN, token: token }),
    ...
};
```

Now in your ContainerComponent you'll need to dispatch this action

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        buttonClickedMethod: () => dispatch(actions.buttonClicked()),
        setToken: (token) => dispatch(actions.setToken(token))
    };
};
```

and

```
componentWillMount(){
    var url = window.location.href;

    var urlLength = url.length;
    var equalSignPos = url.search('=');
    var token = url.substring(equalSignPos+1, urlLength);

    document.cookie = `token=${token}`;
    this.props.setToken(token);
}
```

Finally, in your reducer, catch the action

```
switch (action.type) {
   ...
    case RECEIVED_NEW_TOKEN:
        // whatever you need to do to place your token in state
        // The new token will be in action.token
   ...
}
```